# Set Timeout for All Select queries in MySQL running on RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, relational-database

I want to set a timeout for all the select queries hitting on MySQL Server.
So that if the read query is taking a long time then i can throw a timeout exception. 
I know this feature is provided in MySQL 5.7 by:

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=1000;
```

or

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=1000;
```

But the problem is that MySQL 5.7 is not provided in AWS RDS. I am using MySQL 5.6 on RDS. Please tell me is there any alternate way to do this in 5.6
I am a new to mysql and RDS. Please help me out.

Answer (score 12):

I know this question is about MySQL v5.6.1 - but maybe this helps other visitors:
You can find out what version/parameter is supported and edit it like this:

**1)** Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/ and select  "Parameter groups" in the menu on the left.

**2)** Select the parameter group you used for your database instance and in the dropdown "Parameter group actions" choose "edit".

Now depending on your database version the parameter might be called `max_statement_time` or in later versions `max_execution_time`.

**3)** Search for one of those parameters and click "Edit parameters".

**be aware** that `max_statement_time` is in seconds and `max_execution_time` in milliseconds. So if you want your query to be terminated after 1 second its either:

```
 max_statement_time = 1
```

or

```
 max_execution_time = 1000
```

To be sure, read the explanation on the right column to see what the parameter does.

**4)** Then set the new value you want.

**5)** "Save changes" and wait for the parameter group being applied to the database instance (you might have to select "apply immediately" or just reboot afterwards).

Comment: max_statement_time is not present now

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the ability to set MAX_STATEMENT_TIME was introduced in MySQL v5.7.4 (http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/).

This means that any RDS instance using v5.6 will not be able to have a MAX_STATEMENT_TIME set.

At the time of this reply, the latest version Amazon RDS supports is 5.6.23.

If you are looking to have MySQL v5.7.4 running on an Amazon account, you should look into setting up an EC2 instance instead where you can install MySQL v5.7+ until Amazon makes this version of MySQL available.